# Class 'App\Http\Database\Model' not found

Tags: php, class, autoload

I am using composer to autoload classes, but for some reason class `Model` cannot be found in my `Controller`

### Controller.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Database\Model;

class Controller extends Model
{

    public function insert($query){

        $results = $this->model->query($query)->fetchAll();

        return $results;
    }
}
```

Now what I have in my `Model` file is a simple PDO connection to MySQL

### Model.php

```
namespace app\Http\Database;

class Model extends Database
{
    public $model;

    function __construct()
    {
        try {
            $this->model = new \PDO("mysql:host=".Database::DB_HOST."; dbname=".Database::DB_DATABASE."", "".Database::DB_USER."", "".Database::DB_PASS."", array(\PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false));
            $this->model->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
            return $this->model;

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Cannot connect to the Database";
            die();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what I have on my index.php

### index.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$controller = new Controller();

$query = 'SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id = 1';

print_r($controller->insert($query));
```

### autoload.php

```
$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'App\\Http\\Controllers\\Controller' => $baseDir . '/app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php',
    'App\\Http\\Controllers\\IndexController' => $baseDir . '/app/Http/Controllers/IndexController.php',
    'App\\Http\\Database\\Database' => $baseDir . '/app/Http/Database/Database.php',
    'app\\Http\\Database\\Model' => $baseDir . '/app/Http/Database/Model.php',
);
```

What am I missing here? Can you please point my to the right direction?

Comment: Can you show your autoloading configuration?

Comment: // Add this line
use App\Model;

Comment: As asked, can you show the autoload configurtation? also, pay attention you have set the name space of the Model.php `namespace app\Http\Database`, I assume you meant `App\Http\Database`

Comment: @localheinz, just updated my question, added autoload.php

Comment: @AlexB I meant the configuration in `composer.json`.

Comment: Looks like it is just a typo on the namespace.

Comment: @localheinz here it is `{
  "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
      "app/Http/Controllers",
      "app/Http/Database",
      "app/Http/Core"
    ]
  }
}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you please check the namespace in you Model Class. please rename it to `App\Http\Database`

Comment: Just changed it, but same results so far

Comment: Actually it has been fixed now after rerunning it again, so thanks a a lot, I guess, that letter casing was the issue here

Comment: Composer is a great tool, you just need to make sure you follow the PSR standards well, and would suggest to dump autoload once you make a change. Happy coding mate!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, fix the import:

```
use app\Http\Database\Model;
```

However, you probably want to fix the namespace as already suggested.

Comment: Here is an error: `Fatal error: Class 'App\Http\Database\Model' not found in C:\Users\Xampp\htdocs\project123\app\Http\Controllers\Controller.php on line 14`